# How to add a s Stream Builder for a Icon Button's Badge using Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image]I've been working on a shopping app using flutter and firebase. I got stuck when i need to create a stream for the wish list of  users . I need to create a stream builder for a Badge (badges package)Button in my appBar. Thanks in Advance :)
The following is my Badge Code. I've added the app's & Firebase console Pictures[image]

```
Badge(
  position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 0, end: 1),
  badgeColor: Colors.white,
  badgeContent: //My Stream Builder
  child: IconButton(
      onPressed:(){},
      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline_rounded,color: Colors.black,)),
   )
```

Comment: Can you please share what exactly the `StreamBuilder` will be providing to `badgeContent` and from where it will be sinked ?

Comment: The content will be from the wish_list from firestore ( you can refer the above picture) . It gets the wish_list data and makes a stream to the badge content.